# How does this function compute the number of nodes in binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I've a function that I'm trying to analyze which its output is 7:

**Given this block of code:**

```
int func_1(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return func_1(node->left) + 1 + func_1(node->right);
}
```

**And this Binary Search Tree:**
[image]

The return value is 7.

I know recursion and it's kinda simple here, I tried to follow up and I can not understand how it returned 7. I calculated that it just goes left, left, then one time right, and that's it. which will return 3. And even if it goes 3 times right, after the root, it will still return 6 and not 7.

Can you guys help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically it takes the number of left nodes + 1 (the current node) + the number of right nodes.

with func_1(x) I mean calling the function on that specific node.

So the complete calculation is

- func_1(8) + 1 + func_1(14)
- (func_1(7) + 1 + func_1(9)) + 1 + func_1(14)
- (1 + 1 + 1) + 1 + (0 + 1 + func_1(17)
- 3 + 1 + (0 + 1 + (0 + 1 + func_1(18))
- 3 + 1 + (1 + (1 + (0 + 1 + 0)
- results in 7

This principle is used very often in recursion:

- first do the calculation for the 'current' item (the current node), in this case the number of nodes for the 'node itself' is 1.
- than add the calculation of the other items in a recursive way, in this case the number of nodes left of the current node, and the number of nodes right of the current node. For ordering reasons in this case the +1 for the current node (number of nodes) is put in the middle.

Comment: This was going to be my exact explanation! Clear and to the point.

Comment: For your clarity I added some rationale about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the leaf node 7.

When `func_1` is called with the value of the node 7, the if statement will branch into the else part, since the pointer to this node is valid.

Then `func_1` will be called twice once for the left child and once for the right child. In both cases the functions return 0, since left and right child are NULL. The function will return 1:

```
return func_1(node->left) + 1 + func_1(node->right);
```

equivalent to:

```
return func_1(NULL) + 1 + func_1(NULL);
```

becomes:

```
return 0 + 1 + 0;
```

Comment: I got it now. Thank you 2501!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this statement

```
return func_1(node->left) + 1 + func_1(node->right);
                          ^^^^^
```

if a node is not equal to NULL it counts itself plus the number of nodes in the left and right sub trees relative to this node.

So you will get a result that is equal to the number of nodes that are not equal to NULL.